# How to "Set Value..." when debugging with Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, debugging, dart, flutter

### Problem

The following image and code are the defaults when creating Flutter App with "New Flutter Project".

[image]

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(

          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      );
    }
  }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

    final String title;

    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    int _counter = 0;

    void _incrementCounter() {
      setState(() {

        _counter++; // <- I set a breakpoint

      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(

          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: new Center(

          child: new Column(

            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              new Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      );
    }
  }
```

I attempted to "Set Value..." by putting a break point in the code where _counter is incremented when debugging with this code, but can not be pressed even if I hover the cursor.

[image]
①　"Debug 'main.dart' (^D)"
②　Breakpoint
③　"Set Value..."

### Question

- How to "Set Value..." when debugging with Flutter in Android Studio.

### Development Environment

- Android Studio 3.1.4
- Flutter 0.5.1
- Dart 2
- Android SDK built for x86

Best regards,

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Comment: I couldn't solve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While the execution halts on a breakpoint, `setState` has no effect.
`setState` doesn't directly cause to rerender, it just marks the widget as required for rerender.

The next time the sync signal comes from the display, Flutter rebuilds the stale parts of the view.

Comment: In this case, where should I place a breakpoint, which variable can be "Set Value ..."?

Comment: You can call `setValue`, what variable you update doesn't really matter, but you would need to continue execution to see the effect of `setValue`

Comment: I can not press the "Set Value ..." button.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is there any way where we can write `array [0]`, `array[1]` or any run time assignment in the debugger ?

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but as mentioned, it doesn't cause UI re-render. `setState()` needs to be called to invalidate the view and then Flutter needs to render again, but it can't because the execution is halted at the breakpoint.

Comment: This is not an answer to the "How to...?". We still can't change variables at the runtime. Case which described in the question is specific. I want to change the var in the `bloc` or `repository`, or even in the widget before render, but I can't.